# Bot installation in Group Chats (Conversation Groups not Teams Channels) in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, botframework

## Unable to install bot in Group Chats (Conversation Groups not Teams Channels) having Chat ThreadId or through anyways

We have these Beta API:

For adding an app to the team:

- POST /teams/{id}/installedApps

For adding app for user:

- POST /users/{id}/teamwork/installedApps

I need a similar API or something to add the app to group chats without adding it manually using @GetBots

Comment: When you say @GetBots are you referring the following step - "Where you write messages and replies, just type "@" and then select Get bots to add a bot to an existing 1:1 or group chat" or different?

Comment: @Dev yes, I am referring to the same step, I want to do that using C# or any API if available

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible to do this - as you've identified, there is no Graph endpoint to add a bot to a Group chat, only personal and Teams channels.

Comment: Can we add a bot to a group chat using any other way?

Comment: As of now there is no API to do this but someone from Group chat has to add bot.

Comment: So, is there any other way to send a message to the group chat?